# Best way to tally two columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a basic upvoting and downvoting system in rails. I have a column that keeps track of upvotes and one that keeps track of downvotes.  Is there a way I can subtract these columns (perhaps by way of a helper) to show the tally of votes between the two?

I tried this with a helper:

```
module PostsHelper
  def count_votes(up, down)
    @total = (up-down)
    return @total
  end
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-left">

    <%= link_to 'Upvote',  upvote_post_path(post), method: :patch, remote: true %>

   <%= link_to 'Downvote', downvote_post_path(post), method: :patch, remote: true %>

     <%= count_votes(post.up_vote, post.down_vote) %>

  <%= post.title %>
  <%= post.content %>
</div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

But that yields this error:

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there an ideal way to do this? Should I be using something in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance method in model. Something like:

```
# models/post.rb

  def count_votes
    (up || 0) - (down || 0) # "|| 0" because subtracting from `nil` will throw `nil:NilClass` error.
  end
```

Now you can call `post.count_votes` from view to get the desired result.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.  So you recommend doing this in the model rather than helpers?

Comment: Yes. It should belongs to model.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like default value for post.up_vote(and also post.down_vote) columns is NULL. Hence `@total = (up-down)` is failing.

You can fix this by having default value for `up_vote` and `down_vote` as `0`

You can either add this at database level, by specifying `default` in migration
or you can keep it at model level if you don't want to touch migrations,
Ex:

```
# post.rb
after_initialize :set_defaults

def set_defaults
  self.up_vote = 0
  self.down_vote = 0
end
```